# Why contextmanager is slow

Tags: python, performance, with-statement

A coworker pointed out to me, that `with` statement can be slow. So I measured and indeed it takes 20 times longer to get value from a `contextmanager` function than from a generator in Python 2.7 and even 200 times longer in PyPy 2.6.

Why is it so? Is it possible to rewrite `contextlib.contextmanager()` to run faster?

For the reference:

```
def value_from_generator():
    def inner(): yield 1

    value, = inner()
    return value

def value_from_with():
    @contextmanager
    def inner(): yield 1

    with inner() as value:
        return value
```

And timings:

```
$ python -m timeit 'value_from_generator()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.169 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit 'value_from_with()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.04 usec per loop
```

Comment: A test that recreates the context manager from scratch every time is not a particularly good test case for the cost of _using_ a context manager. Typically, a `@contextmanager` decorated function is defined once, but used many times; it's like dismissing the use of `class`es and functions because using `dict`s and putting everything inline is faster.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you are right. It looks the `contextmanager` contributes a lot to the slow down. And after that replacing decorator with a context manager class as @krrr suggested speeds things up even more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using profiler and source of contextlib, i found:

```
value_from_with:
 ncalls  tottime  cumtime  filename:lineno(function)
1000000    1.415    4.802  value_from_with  # 1sec more than value_from_generator, likely caused by with statement
1000000    1.115    1.258  contextlib.py:37(__init__)  # better doc string of context manager instance
1000000    0.656    0.976  contextlib.py:63(__exit__)  # optional exception handling
1000000    0.575    1.833  contextlib.py:124(helper)  # "wrapped" in decorator
2000000    0.402    0.604  {built-in method next}  # why it's so expensive?
1000000    0.293    0.578  contextlib.py:57(__enter__)  # a next() call to the generator in try&except block (just for error msg)
2000000    0.203    0.203  inner1
1000000    0.143    0.143  {built-in method getattr}  # better doc string, called by __init__

value_from_generator:
 ncalls  tottime  cumtime  filename:lineno(function)
1000000    0.416    0.546  value_from_generator
2000000    0.130    0.130  inner2
```

It told us: unpacking from generator is faster than using next();
function call is expensive; exception handling is expensive...so the comparison is unfair, and this profiling is just for fun.

It also told us that every time "with" block is executed a instance of context manager is created (almost unavoidable). Besides this, `contextmanager` did some job to convinient us. If you really want to optimize it, you can write a context manager class instead of using the decorator

profiled code:

```
def inner1(): yield 1

def value_from_generator():
    value, = inner1()
    return value

# inner should not be created again and again
@contextmanager
def inner2(): yield 1

def value_from_with():
    with inner2() as value:
        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

This two tools have 'slightly' different purposes, so comparing their performance won't really show anything.

Contextmanagers allow you to perform some operations before and after the code is executed in `with` block. Common use is to occupy resources at start, do the job, perform cleanup, i.e. DB connections, file access, etc.

Generators allow you to code functions, that save the state between calls. Common use to save resources on unneeded(at particular moment) computations, and save memory on not storing all the results of operation at once. So primary use is for computation purposes.

Comment: Indeed, generator and context manager have rather different purposes. I used generator for comparison, as it is intended to be defined as part of the context manager.